# javascript regex trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

Javascript regex

I have following regex, i want to un-match zeros after decimal, 1.0 or 1.00 should not match but should match 1.25 or 1.2

```
^(?!0\.)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

it accepts following inputs

```
1.00
1.25
does not accept leading zero ex. 0.25
100
1000
1,000
100,000
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Trailing zeroes are insignificant anyway so will be ignored by `parseInt`/`parseFloat` - what are you doing with the captured input?

Comment: *"...1.0 or 1.00 should not match..."* *"it accepts following inputs: ... 1.00"* Um, which is it? I'm sorry, but this question isn't at all clear. From the description, you just want `/\.0/` and if a string matches, don't take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a negative lookahead at the end:

```
^(?!0\.)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.(?!0+$)\d{1,2})?$
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cBk4Xh/1)

The `(?!0+$)` negative lookahead restricts the subsequent consuming subpattern `\d{1,2})?$` so that the `\d{1,2}`  cannot match `00` or `0` any longer.

Comment: thanks works, would you mind explaining what is : and ? means

Comment: You mean `(?:...)`? It is a non-capturing group that is only used for *grouping* patterns so as to match a *sequence*. Just `(...)` creates a capturing group and stores the value inside a numbered memory buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks at it from the opposite approach at what is allowed instead of excluded:

```
^[1-9],?[0-9]*.?[1-9]*$
```